# Prove that the set of functions $\sin kx$ is closed and bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given a set of functions $M=\lbrace f_k \rbrace$, where $f_k = \sin (kx)$, prove that M is closed and bounded.

I have been given a norm: 
$$\| f\| = \left[ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f (x)^2 dx \right]^{1/2}$$
(on the space of continuous, real functions from $[0,2\pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}$), 
 but no metric or topology. I don't see how I can do this.

Comment: What norm had you been given? Also, a norm automatically gives you a metric ($\therefore$ also a topology).

Comment: The norm was on the space of continuous, real functions from $[0, 2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as:

$|| \cdot || = \left[ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f (x)^2 dx \right]^{1/2} $

Comment: use the open ball topology, defining $B(r, \epsilon) := \{x \in X : ||x-r|| < \epsilon\}$

Comment: Thanks, man! I did it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General remarks

- A norm induces a metric: $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$.
- A metric induces a topology, via neighborhoods $N(x,r) = \{y:d(x,y)<r\}$. Which becomes  $N(x,r) = \{y:\|x-y\|<r\}$ when the metric comes from a norm.

#### Specific set

Boundedness amounts to a direct computation: $\|f_k\| = \pi^{1/2}$

The reason the set is closed is that its points are uniformly far apart; as a result, the set has no limit points. To justify this, compute $\|f_k-f_j\| = (2\pi)^{1/2}$ for $k\ne j$.

The computations are based on double-angle and product-to-sum [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).